# Normalization and magnitude of a vector.

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis

What is difference between normalization and magnitude of a vector. We compute them with same formula but i don't know any geometric difference between them. Please help me on this.
Regards

Comment: You do not (or *should not*) compute them with the same formula.

Comment: Normalization is a unit vector with the same direction as the given vector.  Magnitude is the length.  One is a vector, the other a scalar.

Answer (score 2):

You *normalize* a vector by dividing it by its *magnitude*.

I.e., for a vector $v$, $\|v\|$ is the magnitude of $v$, and $\frac{v}{\|v\|}$ is the normalization of vector $v$.

Comment: Excellent.  Now i know the difference between them.

Answer (score 0):

In case you have some confusion regarding Normalization and Norm of a vector (I guess you don't) check here...
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VectorNorm.html

Answer (score -1):

You may find this link useful. It gives a good visualisation of the two.

https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-programming/programming-natural-simulations/programming-vectors/a/vector-magnitude-normalization